# strptime() behaving differently in an anonymous function than I expected

Tags: r, xts, quantmod, strptime

I have an xts list object, I am trying to get the dates present in my list put then in a vector to be used latter as xts index in further processing.  Although my data include a time stamp, for the purpose of this illustration I am pulling YHOO data from google. This data doesn't have the time element of a time stamp only date but it's good enough. You need `quantmod`. I pull the data, then create a list to divide YHOO into weekly sub-components with the following code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(xts)

getSymbols("YHOO",src="google")
yhooL <- split.xts(YHOO,"weeks")
```

To get the date from the first piece of yhooL I pass this code:

```
strptime(index(yhooL[[1]][1]),format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

It works as expected and I get my date. But to get all of the dates from the first row of each week using `vapply` `strptime()` returns all its eleven elements $sec, $min...days, week of year. It doesn't give me the date in the format I provided. What I am trying to achieve is return the date from the first row in that particular format.  I am not sure what value to pass to argument FUN.VALUE of `vapply()`

```
vapply(yhooL, function(i) {strptime(index(i[1,]), format ="%Y-%m-%d")},double(1))
```

I also tried `POSIXct(1)` for `FUN.VALUE` and a bunch of other, was guessing without luck really.

Comment: Can you try as.Date()?

Comment: for the FUN.VALUE?  if that's what you meant no because the error is occurring because strptime() is returning 11 elements and the function is expecting 1.  That is 11 per (i) instead of 1 per (i).

Comment: `strptime` converts strings to POSIXlt objects. `index` returns a time based object. So, it's not clear why you need `strptime`.

Comment: I am trying to get the date component from a time stamp.  my index consists of date and time and I am trying to get the date only. or the first second of each date (mid-night).

Comment: When I load above data, the index is just a date field and is of date class. Is there a different way you run that is resulting in a timestamp?

Comment: @  user3949008, yes i wasn't at my main machine and didn't have the data I work with so I got it from the net.  The resulting error in both cases are exactly the same.

Comment: @ user394900 I got xts object with time stamp from the lakers data set distributed with the Lubridate package.  I passed the following code on it to put the date and time together.

Comment: xts(lakers[,-c(1,4)], as.POSIXct(paste(lakers[,1],lakers[,4]),format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M"), unique=F)

Comment: There might be a solution in Lubridate also using round_date(x,"day"), not sure it would work with vapply, but it might be an alternative to strptime().  Apparently there is also a base function called round.POSIXt().  I will be looking at these funcitons in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `strptime` returns a `POSIXlt` object, which is pretty complicated. You are better off using `lapply` to pick the indices out and then using do.call to combine them after. You can also set the class of the final object in this way, eg using `as.Date`.

```
x <- do.call(c,lapply(yhooL, function(i) as.Date(index(i)[1])))
summary(x)
        Min.      1st Qu.       Median         Mean      3rd Qu.         Max. 
"2007-01-03" "2009-04-02" "2011-07-05" "2011-07-04" "2013-10-03" "2016-01-04" 
class(x)
[1] "Date"
```

Comment: Their data is not daily though, so you need to extract the first element, as they show in their question: `do.call(c, lapply(yhooL, function(i) as.Date(index(i)[1])))`